# ActiveScaffold - Specifying Conditions in Embedded Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I have a Project model and a TaskType model. 
Association between the two occurs through a ProjectTaskType model 
(backed by a link/join table in the DB with foreign keys to both Projects and 
TaskTypes).

A Project has_many TaskTypes :through ProjectTaskType, and a TaskTypes 
has_many Projects :through ProjectTaskType.

I have a vew with an embedded scaffold and want to display all 
TaskTypes belonging to a given Project.

Can someone quide me as to how I would write the conditions for this?

```
<%= render 
   :active_scaffold => :task_type, 
   :label => 'Task Types', 
   :conditions => "TaskTypes which are associated with @project 
                   through the ProjectTaskType" %>
```

And can my filtering logic go elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the ActiveSacffold controller I added this AS hook method...

def conditions_for_collection
   subquery = "SELECT t.id 
          from #{TaskType.table_name} t, #{ProjectTaskTypes.table_name} ptt
          where (t.id = ptt.task_type_id and ptt.project_id = #{project_id})"

"id in (#{subquery})"
end